# jQuery autocomplete too many db requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, autocomplete

How to solve problem of too many requests to a database when using db data in jQuery ajax autocomplete widget? Basically every time the user inserts a letter, the script makes a ajax request to a database, what are the best practises to keep db requests to minimal?

**I get the data from third party app so i have to consider that it can change in my application.**

Comment: you can use minLength property of jquery autocomplate.

Comment: Why not try Scrollable? look example: https://anseki.github.io/jquery-ui-autocomplete-scroll/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem few months ago.
I found two solutions :

**Solution 1 :**
Don't start the query from the first letter typed. Use the "minLength" Autocomplete attribute. [minLength documentation here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-minLength). With that attribute added, the first query will start at *n* where *n* is the number (integer) of letter previously typed.
Example :

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 3
});
```

**Solution 2 :**
Add a (very short but nice for the database) delay between multiples send. A short one like 250/300/500ms (depending of which ping you have between you and the database, or users bandwidth) is really appreciable. [Delay documentation link here](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay). Value is in milliseconds (integer).
Example :

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
    delay: 500
});
```

I hope it will match to your needs.
Don't hesitate to use both of two.

Answer (score 5):

You can throttle or debounce the requests. These functions are often included in libraries like Lodash (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#debounce).

Debounce: When a key is pressed, a timer starts. When the timer ends you make the Ajax call. When during the timer another key is pressed, the timer gets reset.

Throttle: When a key is pressed, a Ajax call is made and a timer starts. When another key is pressed while the timer is running, it is ignored.

Comment: +1 for teaching new concepts associated with the issue. Sorry for not accepting your answer. Both yours and @Aethyn answers were useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

As @Remq say, you can try this

```
  $("your_selector").autocomplete({
     source: debounce(querySourceData, 1000),
  });

  function debounce(fn, delay) {
    var timer;
    return function() {
      var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
      var context = this;
      if (timer) {
        window.clearTimeout(timer);
      }
      timer = window.setTimeout(function() {
        fn.apply(context, args);
      }, delay);
    };
  };

  function querySourceData(request, response) {
     $.ajax({
        url: '/your_api',
        success: function(data = []) {
           response(data);
        },
        error: function() {
           response([]);
        }
     });
  }
```